# Merging two mostly similar adapters for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two adapters that adapt to a recycler view depending on different conditions. I want to merge them.

The issue is that I created first in the same file as the activity where it is being used and the other is in a new file.

Take it as follows:
DefaultAdapter is in the file where it is being used.
AutoCompleteAdapter is also used in the same file but is declared in other file.

I want to get rid of Default Adapter and get its funtions into AutoCompleteAdapter.

There are some issues to it: I can no more use the ParentFiles' variables.

Below is the adapter that I want to get rid of.

```
  public class DefaultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DefaultAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    List<String> searchList;

    @NonNull @Override
    public DefaultAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
      ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
      return holder;
    }

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.txt.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)).toString());///need to get rid of this error
    }

    @Override public int getItemCount() {
      return searchList.size();
    }

    @NonNull public String getItem(int position) {
      return searchList.get(position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      TextView txt;

      public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = txt.getText().toString();
            searchPresenter.saveSearch(title);
          }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
          @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            String searched = txt.getText().toString();
            deleteSpecificSearchDialog(searched);
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Please take note of the SearchPresenter. This is a variable in the parent file, that is causing major issues. Autocomplete adapter doesn't have to use it, but default have to.

This is the adapter I want it to merge into

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AutoCompleteAdapter.ViewHolder>
  implements Filterable {

  @Inject JNIKiwix currentJNIReader;
  @Inject SharedPreferenceUtil sharedPreferenceUtil;
  @Inject ZimReaderContainer zimReaderContainer;
  private List<String> data;
  private KiwixFilter kiwifilter;
  private Context context;

  public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    kiwifilter = new KiwixFilter();
    setupDagger();
  }

  private void setupDagger() {
    CoreApp.getCoreComponent().inject(this);
  }

  @NonNull @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
      .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
  }

  @Override public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)).toString());
  }
  @Override
  public String getItem(int index) {
    String a = data.get(index);
    if (a.endsWith(".html")) {
      String trim = a.substring(2);
      trim = trim.substring(0, trim.length() - 5);
      return trim.replace("_", " ");
    } else {
      return a;
    }
  }

  @Override public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      title = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    }
  }
}
...
```

Note the similarity between the two, they are almost similar,  autocompleteadapter is like superset of defaultadapter.

I just want to get rid of the default adapter.

Note: I have chopped off some other things from autocompeleteadapter, I think they are not required for the problem.
Noob here...
Thanks

Comment: what you want to acheive

Comment: I am given a job of cleaning the code. If you observe the two adapters can be merged. What I want is that get rid of default adapter.

Comment: @kam1234 So I want to merge them. But the issue is that both are stored in different files: Default is in the same file where it is used, and Auto is in new file. So I can't use the variables used in default in auto.

Comment: @kam1234 I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @kam1234 I have edited the question.